# Optimization of $e^{x^2 + y}$ on $x+y \leq 2$

Tags: calculus, optimization

> Let $f(x,y) = e^{x^2 + y}$ and $M = {(x,y): x+y \leq 2}$.
>
> A. $f(x,y)$ on M is bounded above and not bounded below
>
> B. $f(x,y)$ on M achieves global minimum(a).
>
> C. (0,0) is point of local minimum of $f(x,y)$ on M.

Every claim is false. I've difficulties with disproving B.

A is false: take $\lim_{t \rightarrow - \infty} f(t,0)$ which is clearly increasing without bound.

C is false: the point is in interior of M, so we can disregard the constraint and use usual first-order conditions which must hold at that point.

$$\begin{cases}
e^{x^{2}+y}\cdot2x=0\\
e^{x^{2}+y}\cdot1=0
\end{cases}$$

Obviously, no point in interior satisfies FOC, hence C is false.

Now, help me please with B. I know that $exp(z) > 0 $, but how can I make sure that the lower bound isn't some $a>0$?

Comment: You may exploit the fact that $f$ is log-convex and positive, hence convex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exponential function evaluated on real numbers cannot be negative, so $\inf_{(x,y)\in M} e^{x^2+y}\geq0$. On the other hand, we note that 
$$
\lim_{y\to -\infty} f(0,y)=\lim_{y\to -\infty} e^y =0,
$$
so the infimum actually equals zero. However, since there does not exist $z\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $e^z=0$, this infimum is not a minimum, so there's no global minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose B is true: there is $(x_0,y_0)\in M$ such that $0<m=f(x_0,y_0)\leq f(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}$. However, for some $y_1$ sufficiently negative, we have $\exp(y_1)<m$ (i.e. any $y_1<\log(m)$ will do) and we have a contradiction: $f(0,y_1)<m=f(x_0,y_0)$. In particular, $(0,y_1)\in M$ so $f$ doesn't even achieve a minimum on $M$, let alone globally.